# How to create a square or rectangle overlay(plane) over camera with given width and height programmatically using Scenekit(ARKit) iOS 11?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, xcode9-beta, arkit

I am new to AR and i want to create a square or rectangle overlay based on the given width and height over camera using iOS 11 ARKit- Scenekit.

I tried using https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip and it shows a focus square at the centre using which we can position any 3D model. But it is really unstable.

Is it possible to create a plane similar to the focus square in the above sample based on the size of 3D model that we are going to place, so that

1) We can drag the plane anywhere

2) Rotate the plane

3) Place a 3D model over the focus square(Plane)

Something similar to this http://www.madewitharkit.com/post/163259313638/arkit-furniture-dropping-app-by

Comment: Yes, all of this is possible. What have you tried so far, and where are you having problems?

Comment: @PDK I tried resizing the given focus square in the sample code but it is not working as expected. Can you please direct me on how to create a square or rectangle(empty square or rectangle-only border) in SCNNode and place it horizontal to x axis like given in the  http://www.madewitharkit.com/post/163259313638/arkit-furniture-dropping-app-by demo.

Comment: Try to update your original posts explaining (concisely) what you did so far and what was the result of that (e.g. an error message—and how you were unable to find a solution for that), and don't forget to mention which sources you've already used.

If you are in doubt _how, please read_ (if you haven't already): https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you get the answer ???

Comment: Not exactly. But i ended up creating SCNNode/SCNPlane with my 3D object width and height and added it to scene. Something similar to the answer from @Lebron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to implement your need: prepare a rectangle icon, and generate a `SCNNode` with the method:

```
func geometryNodeFromImage(named name: String, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, length: CGFloat) -> SCNNode {
    let box = SCNBox(width: width, height: height, length: length, chamferRadius: 0)

    let rectangleMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    rectangleMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: name)
    box.materials = [rectangleMaterial]

    return SCNNode(geometry: box)
}
```